# Key not valid for use in specified state. After IIS Reset

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, single-sign-on, wif

I tried this:

> runas /user: domain\user cmd with no luck

This seems to only occur now when IIS is reset and I try to resume my browsing session. So I am logged into the application, I reset IIS on the server, refresh the page and see the error.

I am building an application in .NET 4.0 MVC with a Secure Token Service that is using WIF 4.0. Everything works as expected, except this case. I even tried to use a custom error page, but the error is happening there as well. Because of that, I can't get the custom page to show either. Also, This is using a certificate that is located on both load balanced servers. This happens in my dev environment whihc consists of only one server (app, wfe, db operated there)

One thing I noticed is that if I switch my IIS APP Pool user back to Network Service account it doesn't throw the error any more. We have some restrictions (mostly network related) in the application that we need to use an account in our AD for the app pool sections

Anybody have any experience with this issue?

> Key not valid for use in specified state.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for
>   use in specified state.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state. ]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +428
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[]
>   encoded) +54
>
> [InvalidOperationException: ID1073: A CryptographicException occurred
>   when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see
>   inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be
>   due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set
>   to false. ]
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[]
>   encoded) +146
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[]
>   cookie, Boolean outbound) +113
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader
>   reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +647
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[]
>   token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +105
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[]
>   sessionCookie) +262
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken&
>   sessionToken) +76
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +53
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: Sounds like an Encrypted Connection String which explains why switching app pool users back to orig resolves issue. Try decrypting string, then changing app pool users.

Comment: hmmm interesting, but my connection strings are not being encrypted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to session cookies.

WIF protects session cookies using Data Protection API (**[DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection)**) by default, and the DPAPI is closely related to *machine keys*.

If the keys used to encrypt the session cookies change, it throws this exception.

It could be also related to your app hosting infrastructure.

- if your app is running in an Network Load Balancer (NLB) environment
- if you change the app pool settings (*e.g.*, change the pool’s user)

More details about this scenario on the MSDN blog entry:

> ### [WIF 1.0 – ID1073 A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2012/10/29/wif-1-0-id1073-a-cryptographicexception-occurred-when-attempting-to-decrypt-the-cookie-using-the-protecteddata-api/) <sup>[Archive.Today Shortlink](https://archive.fo/QByuh)</sup>
>
> Todd Foust (October 29, 2012)

So, if your app runs in NLB environment, you could :

- Configure your load balancer to use sticky sessions. This means that your user will be directed to the same server during the session duration. (I’m not very fond of that one)
- Use a certificate to encrypt the session cookies
- set all `web.config` files to use the same *machine key* in `system.web`

If you are not running the app in a NLB env, you could try:

- set the `machinekey` in your `web.config` to use a pre-defined value instead of auto-generated values

Regarding auto-generated `machinekey` setting, please see:

> [How unique is your machine key?](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/how-unique-is-your-machine-key/)<sup>[Archive.Today Shortlink](https://archive.fo/oEqKU)</sup>